# Will [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: ...] always send completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Most likely a rather trivial question but will the completion block always be called using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: ...]`? OR do I have to implement a timeout timer?

Consider the following where I add a `MBProgressView` before the call and remove it ONLY in the completion block:

```
[self showHUDWithTitle:@"Configuring"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data,
                                           NSError *error) {

     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil) {
         [self hideHUDWithFlag:YES 
                      andTitle:@"Finished" 
                   andSubtitle:@"(Box was configured)"];

     } else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
         [self hideHUDWithFlag:NO 
                      andTitle:@"Failed" 
                   andSubtitle:@"(Check box connection)"];
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");

     } else if (error != nil) {
        [self hideHUDWithFlag:NO 
                     andTitle:@"Error" 
                  andSubtitle:@"(Check box connection)"];
         NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: naturally. a completion handler is a COMPLETION handler -- not a success handler :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan I'm the success handler, not the completer that completes the completion!

Comment: if(!error) = success :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the completion handler is always called. If the request fails due to a timeout, the `error` will be set and `data = nil`.

A `NSURLRequest` has a default timeout of 60 seconds, but you can assign a different value to `request.timeoutInverval` before starting the connection. So there is no need for an extra timer.

*Added:* In the case of a timeout:

- `[error domain]` is `NSURLErrorDomain`, and
- `[error code]` is `NSURLErrorTimedOut`,

If you just want to present an error message, you can use `[error localizedDescription]`, which  is "The request timed out." in this case. (This may depend on the locale.)

Comment: @Filip: You are welcome. I have added some information how you can check for a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed             
                                          timeoutInterval:20];
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you did and why. People rarely learn from code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: ...] will definitely call a completion block in any scenario. However if you want to restrict this process to the max time, you can use the timeout timer as well.

For progress bar, how will you be incrementing the value? Instead of progress bar, I would suggest you to go with activity indicator.

Hope this helps.