# ios sendAsynchronousRequest timer

Tags: ios, timeout, sendasynchronousrequest

This is my situation:

Im using sendAsynchronousRequest. I quickly relized that it has a default timeout of 60 seconds. My app is designed to wait for an opponent to start the game (its a word-game).
Actually, it could take hours before the opponent starts the game. Which means the async-request could be waiting for hours.
Is that bad? I mean, I can probably change the default timeout. But the question is if this iss a bad design. The thing is that I wanted to avoid pulling the server at intervals to know if the opponent has started the match or not.
If this is a bad design: can somebody suggest an alternativ way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518316/will-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-always-send-completion-block Look for the information in above link.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to poll the server if you want to be up and running quickly and don't have a lot of resources (time/money).

If for some reason you need more real-time then there is a high amount of complexity involved in creating an open socket to your server for communication and you are best off using an existing framework like Pusher ($), PubNub ($) or socket.io (free but you will have to handle the server side). If you want to create your own client/server notification system then you may want to check out [SocketRocket](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/02/socketrocket-websockets.html) from Sqaure which provides a client side WebSocket implementation for iOS.

Comment: Well, node.js is what Im using on the server. The problem is on the client, i.e. iOS who is ending the async request after 1 minute.

Comment: Well node.js supports all the solutions I outlined above. If you want simple push notifications, you can try WebSockets with SocketRocket. If you want more advanced features like guaranteed deliverability (when users go offline), presence detection, etc and have some $$ to spend then try out Pusher or Pubnub.